# command line Start.Info.Argument error

Tags: c#, command-line, wix, heat

I would like run this command with C# :

> "%WIX%/bin/heat.exe" dir "C:\Documents and Settings\APP" -gg -sfrag
>   -cg Appli -out wixappli.wxs

I have this code (Program.cs) :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process1.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
process1.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/k \"%WIX%/bin/heat.exe\" dir \"{0}\" -gg -sfrag -cg Appli -out wixappli.wxs ",
@"C:\Documents and Settings\APP");
process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Documents and Settings\test";
process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process1.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
process1.Start();
```

Error:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal command or external
>   command

I don't understand because without C#, it works.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, path environments (%windir%, %temp%, etc) uses backslashes (\). try modifying your arguments to use backslashes instead of slashes (\"%WIX%  \  bin  \  heat.exe\"...

Comment: No, i tried and it not works. But without C# it works with /bin/heat.exe .It's weird

Comment: open cmd and execute: 'echo %wix%'. what is the result?

Comment: I have C:\Program Files\WiX Toolset v3.9\

Comment: Notice it ends with a backslash. instead of "%WIX%/bin, use "%WIX%bin

Comment: No same error : 'C:\Program' is not recognized. I don't understand because when i execute into cmd "echo %WIX%bin" i have C:\Program Files\WiX Toolset v3.9\bin

Comment: I believe double-quoting will help. try: String.Format("/k \"\"%WIX%/bin/heat.exe\" dir \"{0}\" -gg -sfrag -cg Appli -out wixappli.wxs\"",@"C:\Documents and Settings\APP");

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you.